# Custom columns for taxonomy list table

Tags: taxonomy, columns, wp-list-table, screen-columns

I have the following code to add a new column to my taxonomy edit screen (`edit-tags.php?taxonomy=book_place&post_type=books`)

```
function add_book_place_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['foo'] = 'Foo';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-book_place_columns', 'add_book_place_columns' );

function add_book_place_column_content( $content ) {
    content = 'test';
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'manage_book_place_custom_column', 'add_book_place_column_content' );
```

It's working, but I need to access the current term id in the `add_book_place_column_content` function. How can I do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `manage_{TAXONOMY}_custom_column` filter hook passes 3 arguments:

- `$content`
- `$column_name`
- `$term_id`

So try this:

```
function add_book_place_column_content( $content, $column_name, $term_id ) {
    $term= get_term( $term_id, 'book_place' );
    switch ( $column_name ) {
        case 'foo':
            // Do your stuff here with $term or $term_id
            $content = 'test';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'manage_book_place_custom_column', 'add_book_place_column_content', 10, 3 );
```