# Taxonomy Custom Column - 'manage_{TAXONOMY}_custom_column' filter only passing 2 arguments

Tags: filters, taxonomy, columns

I am trying to add a custom column to the tables shown on the Tags & Categories admin pages in Wordpress.

I have created a function, and added it as a filter using

```
add_filter( 'manage_post_tag_custom_column' , 'my_custom_column' , 10 , 2 );
```

My function is

```
my_custom_column( $out , $name , $term_id ){
  switch( $name ){
    case 'my_column_slug' :
      echo '<pre>';var_dump( func_get_args() );echo '</pre>';
      break;
  }
}
```

My column is shown in the table, with the `<pre>...</pre>` content, but it seems that no `$term_id` is being passed to my function.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(12) "my_column_slug"
}
```

I have referred to a number of resources to confirm that there should be three arguments passed to the function (including [this StackExchange article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77662/9349)). Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using wrong number of arguments in **add_filter**, you specified to get 2 arguments and you are looking for third one:

Update your **add_filter** code to this:

```
add_filter( 'manage_post_tag_custom_column' , 'my_custom_column' , 10 , 3 );
```

The 3 in the end tells the filter to provide all the three arguments to your function.

Comment: Na not genius just checked it properly ;)

Comment: Please - take the "genius" compliment. Makes me feel like less of a goose for making such a silly and simple mistake.

Comment: Happens all the time :), nothing so big..!